# Alterar o nome do arquivo pdf para hash e depois conseguir desfazer o nome para ler novamente

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Estou fazendo uma funcionalidade em um sistema onde;
Um setor qualquer vai fazer o upload de um arquivo importante, este arquivo contém informações sigilosas vinculadas a cada funcionário da empresa. Cada funcionário poderá abrir seu **próprio** arquivo, mas nenhum outro poderá abri-lo.

O arquivo está no formato PDF, e todos seguem uma **regra** de nomenclatura ex: 
`ano-mes-codigofuncionario.pdf`.
O que acontece... quando eu permito que o funcionário baixe seu arquivo, ele vai ver o nome e se ele entender a lógica dos nomes, ele poderá ir alterando o **código do funcionário** e visualizar arquivos de outras pessoas.

Gostaria então, de no momento de salvar o arquivo em disco, gerar um hash baseado nas politicas do nome do arquivo e quando eu precisar identificar o arquivo para designar a cada funcionário eu pudesse "descriptografar" e pegar o nome original. 
O resultado final deve ficar algo como: `fe415d322sefe185d32sd1f51000e1fea6e.pdf`, desta maneira será mais dificil outros funcionários tentarem visualizar outros arquivos.

Aqui eu salvo no disco:

```
private void SalvarArquivo(HttpPostedFile file)
{
    var pathString = DiretorioTemp();

    var fileName1 = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
    bool isExists = Directory.Exists(pathString);

    if (!isExists)
        Directory.CreateDirectory(pathString);

    var path = string.Format("{0}\\{1}", pathString, file.FileName);
    file.SaveAs(path);
}
```

Depois de ler o arquivo eu carrego no click do botão para o usuário, respeitando as regras que são utilizadas para dar nome ao arquivo original.

```
public static void Download(string fName)
    {
        FileInfo fInfo = new FileInfo(fName);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fInfo.Name + "\"");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fInfo.Length.ToString());
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.WriteFile(fInfo.FullName);
        fInfo = null;
    }
```

Obs: Se eu gerar um hash e não conseguir desfaze-lo não adiantará, pois não saberei os parâmetros utilizados na data em que foi inserido os arquivos.

Lembrando que, o windows não permite alguns **caracteres(* / \ < >)** por este motivo gostaria de algo que fosse simples.

Comment: Essas informações não são salvas no banco?

Comment: Não estou salvando no banco.

Comment: Então o caminho é salvar com o nome original e trocar o nome na hora de fazer o download. Tem como colocar na pergunta o código que faz o download do arquivo?

Comment: Você faz download com `Process.Start`???

Comment: Isto, eu só busco o arquivo e jogo para ele na tela (para imprimir)

Comment: Isso não é ASP.NET, né?

Comment: Estou utilizando Process.Start só para fazer o teste de devolver o arquivo, o problema que tenho é inibir o nome para que ele não encontre. É asp.net

Comment: Não sei se entendi. No final de tudo você vai precisar fazer o _download_ do arquivo, certo? Via ASP.NET MVC, né?

Comment: Este projeto ainda está em asp.net WebForms e sim, o resultado final é disponibilizar o download do arquivo.

Comment: Certo. Eu não entendo de WebForms. Tem como colocar na pergunta o código que usa pra fazer _download_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lógica é simplíssima: você mantém os arquivos com os nomes originais no sistema e quando for enviar para *download* mande-o com outro nome

```
public static void Download(string fName)
{
    FileInfo fInfo = new FileInfo(fName);

    HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";

    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + Guid.NewGuid() + ".pdf\""); // Aqui está o segredo

    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fInfo.Length.ToString());

    HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.WriteFile(fInfo.FullName);
    fInfo = null;
}
```

Comment: Fui cego rsrsr, pensei tanto em querer renomear que esqueci do final... É isto mesmo!
Só faltou colocar ali depois do Guid.NewGuid() + ".pdf"

Answer (score 0):

Isso é impossível utilizando [Hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_one-way_hash_function), visto que esse é o propósito do mesmo, ser *oneway*, quando o código é gerado ele não volta.
Para solucionar o seu problema sugiro utilizar [Base64](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).
  em C#:
Para encodar:

```
public static string Base64Encode(string plainText) {
  var plainTextBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
  return System.Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes);
}
```

Para desencodar:

```
public static string Base64Decode(string base64EncodedData) {
  var base64EncodedBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(base64EncodedData);
  return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(base64EncodedBytes);
}
```

Sugiro também usar senha nos arquivos PDF, onde a senha é os 3 primeiros dígitos do CPF dele ou qualquer outro código do gênero. Isso pode ser feito com o [PDF Sharp](http://www.pdfsharp.net/?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1)

```
// Open an existing document. Providing an unrequired password is ignored.
PdfDocument document = PdfReader.Open(filename, "some text");

PdfSecuritySettings securitySettings = document.SecuritySettings;

// Setting one of the passwords automatically sets the security level to 
// PdfDocumentSecurityLevel.Encrypted128Bit.
securitySettings.UserPassword  = "user";
securitySettings.OwnerPassword = "owner";

// Don't use 40 bit encryption unless needed for compatibility reasons
//securitySettings.DocumentSecurityLevel = PdfDocumentSecurityLevel.Encrypted40Bit;

// Restrict some rights.
securitySettings.PermitAccessibilityExtractContent = false;
securitySettings.PermitAnnotations = false;
securitySettings.PermitAssembleDocument = false;
securitySettings.PermitExtractContent = false;
securitySettings.PermitFormsFill = true;
securitySettings.PermitFullQualityPrint = false;
securitySettings.PermitModifyDocument = true;
securitySettings.PermitPrint = false;

// Save the document...
document.Save(filename);
```

[FONTE](http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/ProtectDocument-sample.ashx)

Comment: Base64 vai gerar nomes com caracteres que o windows não permite para nomear arquivos.